# Installing package(s) from local repository

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

I used following method to install packages by local-repository

1. `mkdir /var/my-lcaol-repo` and put all debs inside this folder
2. Create `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/my-local.list` with `deb file:/var/my-local-repo/ ./` and `sudo apt-get update`
3. Install package(s) by `sudo apt-get install [package]`

All working fine but there is one problem:

If package which I'm tiring to install from local-repository (i.e `/var/my-local-repo`) is available from Repository that enabled (example: main or universe) then apt first tries to download packages from online repository and at that time I am not connected to internet , it fails to download archives and stops.

Temporary solution: Disable repository (ex- main or universe) then apt installs package from off-line repository. But I don't want to disable online repository.

Possible solution: Give first priority to off-line repository. **How to?**

Note: same package version (which is available on main/universe repo) is available in offline-repository